# Do you need to convert a JavaScript Date to UTC before calling getVarDate?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I'm working with ActiveX controls in Internet Explorer and need to pass dates to the ActiveX methods that take dates as parameters.  The methods expect dates to be of type, VT_DATE and I can produce VT_DATE values by using the JScript *getVarDate* method on a Date object.

Do I need to first convert a JavaScript Date to UTC before calling *getVarDate?*

I assume that the answer is **no**, but I am not 100% certain and don't know why.

Sample JavaScript code to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
var myDate = new Date(); // Gives me a JavaScript Date object.
console.log(myDate.toString()); // Outputs a string representing the date in the local time zone.
console.log(myDate.toUTCString()); // Outputs a string representing the date in UTC.

var myVT_DATE = myDate.getVarDate();
myActiveXControl.someMethodWantingVT_DATE(myVT_DATE);
```

Comment: I feel like the answer is obvious, but I haven't had my usual allotment of coffee today. If the question is "stupid" I will gladly tag it as [stupid-question] or [duh]....

Comment: I cannot see anything in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d4x3w61(v=vs.94).aspx) that implies that you need to call `myDate.toUTCString()` before calling `myDate.getVarDate()`. Why do you suspect this might be needed?

Comment: @Matt Ball I'm pretty sure it's not needed, but am not very familiar with VT_DATE values.  I'm assuming VT_DATE just represents a date internally as ticks or milliseconds after some arbitrary start date and is therefore time zone independent, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @Matt Ball Also, I looked at the documentation you linked as well and am assuming the statement, "the actual format of the returned value depends on regional settings," supports my assumption.

Comment: According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms931135.aspx), a VT_DATE is _"represented as double-precision numbers, where midnight, January 1, 1900 is 2.0, January 2, 1900 is 3.0, and so on."_

Comment: After working with the problem for a couple of weeks, I have determined that converting the type to `VT_DATE` and ensuring you are using UTC are two different problems.  Converting the type is really a matter of interop with the API, where ensuring UTC is a matter of your application/domain logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any chance of your site being used in more than one timezone, I would recommend using toUTCString().  Each browser will return the local date/time by default (as you've experienced).  This may not seem like a big deal until...

You get deep into the project and it all-of-the-sudden really matters and you're faced with rewrites.

... or worse ...

Your site has been live for months and you now have some need (like reporting) that requires those dates and you realize that you don't know which timezone each date was created in.

Comment: I don't think you read the question correctly. The op needs `getVarDate()` because he needs the JavaScript date object in VT_DATE format so that the code can interface with an ActiveX control.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it is a good way to ensure you have a UTC date before using it. (See my comments with the question to get more context.)